# Drop SQLAlchemy relationship with inheritance

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, pyramid

With SQLAlchemy 1.0.13, is it possible to remove a [relationship join](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/join_conditions.html#configuring-how-relationship-joins) from an inheritance class?

In the next minimal working example I have a parent and two types of childs. The child class has a relationship with the parent class. The AlienChild gets all attributes from Child but I would like to drop the relationship. Is this possible?

```
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer,
                       ForeignKey('parent.id',
                       ondelete='CASCADE'),
                       nullable=False)
    parent = relationship('Parent',
                    backref=backref(
                        'children', cascade="all, delete-orphan"),
                    foreign_keys=[parent_id],
                    single_parent=True)

class AlienChild(Child):
    __tablename__ = 'alienchild'
    parent = droprelationship('Parent')
```

Answer (score 1):

From the top of my head, the first thing I would try is

```
class AlienChild(Child):
    __tablename__ = 'alienchild'
    parent_id = None
    parent = None
```

Which, however, feels kinda weird from the OOP point of view. Also, if you DO NOT remove the relationship from one of the classes the `children` backref will probably stop working - it can't return both Child and AlienChild instances which live in different tables and in no way related to each other. If you want to share only some functionality between classes you can use mixin classes:

```
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class PersonMixin:
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    age = Column(Integer)
    gender = Column(String)

class HasParentMixin:
    parent_id = Column(Integer,
                       ForeignKey('parent.id',
                       ondelete='CASCADE'),
                       nullable=False)
    parent = relationship('Parent',
                    backref=backref(
                        'children', cascade="all, delete-orphan"),
                    foreign_keys=[parent_id],
                    single_parent=True)


class Child(Base, PersonMixin, HasPrentMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'child'


class AlienChild(Base, PersonMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'alienchild'
```